# Operator and Pointer precedence

Tags: c, pointers

Below is the problem I found on the internet.

```
int main()
{

    int a[4] = { 10, 21, 32, 43};
    int *p = a + 3;
    ++*--p;
    ++*p--;


    p[2] += p[1];


    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        printf("%d - %d\t", a[i]);

        return 0;
}
```

//What will be the output?

answer : 10    21     34     77

I understood a lot of things, but the only thing I'm stuck on:

What is the difference between  `(++*--p)` and `(++*p--)`  ?

Shouldn't these two give the same result? Because `(*p--)` and `(*--p)` give the same result in the compiler. The compiler I use is Code::Blocks

Comment: For reference: [C Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: @Oka: Precedence is not an issue here. In both expressions, `--` binds first, then `*`, then `++`, so there is no difference in precedence. The difference is `--p` is a pre-decrement and `p--` is a post-decrement.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Never claimed it to be an answer to the issue. It was a reference, in a comment. *"no difference in precedence"* and having access to documentation that details operator precedence helps explain that, concretely. Documentation that also links through to things like [Order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order), [Member access operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access) and [Increment/decrement operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_incdec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because `(*p--)` and `(*--p)` give the same result in the compiler.

No, they do not. `*p--` decrements `p` but applies `*` to the value of `p` before the decrement. `*--p` applies `*` to the value of `p` after the decrement.

> What is the difference between  `(++*--p)` and `(++*p--)` ?

`++*--p` decrements `p` and increments the object it points to after the decrement.

`++*p--` decrements `p` but increments the object it points to before the decrement.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between `(++*--p)` and `(++*p--)` ?

The difference is that `--p` decrements `p` and resolves to the new value of `p`, whereas `p--` decrements `p` and resolves to the old value of `p`.

`++*` works identically on both - performing indirection on `p`, incrementing the value `p` points to, and resolving to this new value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{   
    int a = 10;         
    int b = 10;         
                       
    /* This prints 9, and `a` is now 9 */
    printf("%d\n", --a);
    /* This prints 10, and `b` is now 9 */
    printf("%d\n", b--);
    
    /* This prints 9 and 9 */
    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
}
```

> Shouldn't these two give the same result? Because `(*p--)` and `(*--p)` give the same result in the compiler.

The order here matters, using `(*--p)` before `(*p--)` would resolve to the same element twice. Using `(*p--)` before `(*--p)` resolves to different elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a[8] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    int *p = a + 4;
    
    /* 4 then 4 */
    printf("%d ", *--p);
    printf("%d\n", *p--);
    
    p = a + 4;
    /* 5 then 3 */
    printf("%d ", *p--);
    printf("%d\n", *--p);
        
}
```